# Fire Base FCM in Native Android When Application in Background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I was integrating fire base cloud Messaging in my native Android App, I'm facing issue when the application is running on background. Currently when the application is running on foreground using the `PendingIntent`, I'm currently opening  my activity  `A Activity` on notification click from the notification Tray and obtained the `Extras`. But when the application is kept background with the `A Activity` and suppose when I received a notification on `notification Tray` and when clicked on the notification , the application is getting launched again `Launcher Activity` which in my case is `B Activity`. But I have to stop launching the app again when the application is in background on  notification click.

```
intent = new Intent(this, AActivity.class);            
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String channelId = "com.a.b";
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, "com.a.b-MESSAGED", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: Are you utilizing data messages or notification messages ? Read about this https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: @Sarah Khan - when application is in background, notification message is consuming from my side. so by clicking the notification, it is directly launching the launcher activity even when the app was not killed.

Comment: @saraKhan - Still facing the issue. Application not resuming from the background when clicking notification from notification tray.

Comment: Any updates on this ??

Comment: Can you please add the json you are sending in the notification?

Comment: @SarahKhan -  Please find the notification payload :  ` {
  "notification": {
    "title": "Hey!  Checkout a new offer for you",
    "body": "15% Discount. We don’t want you to miss out on this one."
  },
  "data": {
    "offer_type":""
  }
}`

Comment: @SarahKhan - any updates on this?